# html style text over image

Tags: html, css

I want to put text over a picture,

I need to change the text box size (so it would be in the same size of the background picture)

I need to be able to change the text font, size, color.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show your html and css

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want a simple CSS background OR AN ACTUAL IMG TAG WITH TEXT OVER IT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I have tried to do that but couldn't success, maybe wordpress is doing some problems

Answer (score 1):

THere are many ways to do it,But simpler one is give below

```
<div style="background-image:url('images.jpg'); ">
    <h1 style="font-size:17px; color:yellow;">Hello word</h1>
</div>
```